# Aggregates in Django and Postgres 9.6 causing invalid SQL

Tags: django, postgresql

I have a Video and VideoLog model. Until now I've been happy enough annotating on a count to see how many times a video has been watched:

```
Video.objects.annotate(
    views=Count('logs'),  # logs is the related name from the VideoLog model
)
```

This works fine on SQLite but we've just upgraded to Postgres 9.6 and trying to run that gives me

```
ProgrammingError: column "video_video.name" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: SELECT "video_video"."id", "video_video"."name", "video_vide...
```

Here's the formatted query it's running:

```
 SELECT "video_video"."id",
       "video_video"."name",
       "video_video"."shorttext",
       "video_video"."text",
       "video_video"."thumbnail",
       "video_video"."product_id",
       "video_video"."slug",
       "video_video"."available_sizes",
       "video_video"."preview_image",
       "video_video"."certificate",
       "video_video"."download",
       Count("video_videolog"."id") AS "views"
FROM   "video_video"
       LEFT OUTER JOIN "video_videolog"
                    ON ( "video_video"."id" = "video_videolog"."video_id" )
GROUP  BY "video_video"."id"
```

The confounding thing is that in another project on the same database, with the similar dependencies, both on fresh virtualenvs, this works fine. I guess I'm going to have to pick through this line-by-line until I find something.

Comment: Django 1.11 is not yet released. Does this happen on django 1.10?

Comment: Exactly the same thing in Django 1.10.

Comment: This might being caused by the pgloader migration. Just tested it on a completely empty database and the query went through fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `pgloader` to upgrade the database. Turns out it also broke a few things. Not sure where, but it must have been pretty subtle because everything else was working quite well.

I know people rag on the `./manage.py dumpdata` → `./manage.py loaddata` workflow (somebody in IRC called it a toy yesterday when I asked for a better option) but if your data is sane, it's bloody accurate. It just saved my bacon.